# js adding mixed multidimentional array into a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I have following js to check if object exists in the `NAMES` variable. If it does not, I want to push the whole object array into the variable as below:

```
var NAMES = {};

function NAME_INFO(name,input1,input2,input3){ 
    return  name : [input1, input2, input3], ;   
}
...
NAMES.push(NAME_INFO(my_name,first,middle,last));   //some variables that I have.
```

The ending result that I am trying to get is as follow:

```
 var NAMES = {
   '185' : ['ryan', 'some', 'last'],
   '15'  : ['mike', 'middle', 'Mcdonald'],
   '122' : ['emily','else', 'Another']
 };
```

I am not sure if this is the right setup for it. I am not sure how to make the function correctly.

Could someone point me to the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: you must define what do you mean by exist. What are the values that you use to compare?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I removed the `if` section as it works fine. I am just having a hard time adding this mixed array into the `NAMES` variable.

Comment: what does "`return  name : [input1, input2, input3], ;`" mean?

Comment: First, fix your syntax errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can not return a map with that function. You need to do this

```
function NAME_INFO(name,input1,input2,input3){ 
    var newMap = {};
    newMap[name] = [input1, input2, input3];
    return newMap ;   
}
```

Secondly, you can not push an object to a MAP object. Your `NAMES` should be define as array i.e. `var NAMES = []`

Your final result will look like

```
var NAMES = [
   {'185' : ['ryan', 'some', 'last']},
   {'15'  : ['mike', 'middle', 'Mcdonald']},
   {'122' : ['emily','else', 'Another']}
];
```

Hope it helps!